# Python - How can I run two dependant funtions at the same time?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have two funtions, one runs increasing by one a number, and the other needs to capture the number that is running the first function every 5 seconds, so that when I capture the first number is 0, the sencond one is 10, the next one is 15, and so on... this is simulating the first function as a sensor. My code is as follows:

```
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

def numero(i=0):
while True:
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    #print i

def capturar():
while True:
    posicion = numero()
    time.sleep(5)
    print posicion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = capturar()).start()
    Thread(target = numero()).start()
```

When I run this code, it keeps in the first function, how can I get this run correctly and obtain the capture of the series of numbers every 5 seconds?

Comment: First thing first, `numero` never returns or yields anything, so you'll always get `None` from `numero()`

Comment: Calling this: `posicion = numero()` will again start the first counter loop inside your second thread.

Comment: if you can upgrade to `3.5`+, `asyncio` would help substantially with `async` and `await`

Comment: @MatthewStory But the OP wants to do this with threading in Python 2. And that's reasonable, although they really ought to migrate to Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not sure doing anything with Threads in python is reasonable :troll: ;).

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- `i` is not in scope for `capturar`
- you execute `capturar` and `numero` instead of handing the functions themselves to `Thread`
- As Matt Clark commented, you call `numero` from `capturar`, which never returns, so `capturar` can't even do one full loop.

To help with the first one, the easiest solution is to wrap the functions into a class, and make `i` into an instance state (as an attribute). The second one merely requires you to remove the extra parentheses. The third one is resolved with the first one, as there is no function call required any more to fetch the counter state.

This should do what you want:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class Contador:
    def __init__(self, comienzo = 0):
        self.numero = comienzo

    def producir(self):
        while True:
            self.numero += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def capturar(self):
        while True:
            posicion = self.numero
            time.sleep(5)
            print posicion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Contador()
    Thread(target = c.capturar).start()
    Thread(target = c.producir).start()
```

Comment: Nice code, but why do you set the value of `posicion` but then sleep for 5 seconds before printing it? Wouldn't it be better to print the latest value?

Comment: @PM2Ring Don't ask me, ask OP. If that's an error, it's a business logic error, not a Python error.

Comment: Ok, I can't disagree with that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Amadan, the soution that you share is working perfectlym but when I tried to pull it into the real sensor (GPS), I am getting only "0"

```
import gps
import itertools
import json
import os
import portdetect
import time
import serial
from threading import Thread

(puerto1, puerto2) = portdetect.detectar_puerto()
print puerto1, puerto2
port = serial.Serial(puerto1, 115200, timeout=1)

os.system('sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket')
time.sleep(2)
comando = 'sudo gpsd ' + puerto2 + ' -F /var/run/gpsd.sock'
os.system(str(comando))
#print str(comando)

# Listen on port 2947 (gpsd) of localhost
session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

class Contador:
    def __init__(self, comienzo = 0):
        self.raw_datos = comienzo

    def leergps(self):
        while True:
            try:
                report = session.next()
                # Wait for a 'TPV' report and display the current time
                # To see all report data, uncomment the line below
                # print report
                if report['class'] == 'TPV':
                    if hasattr(report, 'time') or hasattr(report, 'lat') or hasattr(report, 'lon') or hasattr(report,
                                                                                                              'speed'):
                        datos = [report.time, report.lat, report.lon, report.speed]
                        clave = ['tiempo', 'lat', 'lon', 'speed']
                        diccionario = dict(itertools.izip(clave, datos))
                        self.raw_datos = (json.dumps(diccionario))
                    # print raw_datos
                    return self.raw_datos
                else:
                    return report['class']
            except:
                print "Error de coordenadas"

    def capturar(self):
        while True:
            posicion = self.raw_datos
            time.sleep(5)
            print posicion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Contador()
    Thread(target = c.capturar).start()
    Thread(target = c.leergps()).start()
```

I am trying only to pull the "raw data obtained every 5 seconds, but I am not achieving this"